# C++ object deletion crashing

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I tried to include all necessary code that may be causing these problems.
The program crashes the second time this code is run:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < player.projectiles.size(); i++)
        {
            bool temp = player.projectiles[i].move(begin, WIDTH);
            if (temp == true)
            {
                player.projectiles[i].destroy();
                player.projectiles.erase(player.projectiles.begin() + i);
            }
        }
```

Player.projectiles is a vector of objects from the class Projectiles.
The member function move works perfectly and the function destroy looks like this:

```
void Projectile::destroy()
{
    delete this;
}
```

The first time the loop is run everything works fine, but the second time my program crashes and I can't figure out why. I suspect it has to do with deleting the object. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `delete this` is a somehwat scary thing that must be used with great care. You can find resources about `delete this`, that might help you. Some things to keep in mind: only objects created with `new` may be deleted. After deleting `this`, none of the object's fields or methods should ever be accessed again. Breaking these rules will result in a crash or worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not storing `Projectile*` *pointers* in your `vector`, you are storing actual `Projectile` *objects* (as evident by the fact that your loop is accessing members of the `Projectile` class  using `operator.` instead of `operator->`).  So, calling `destroy()` on any of those objects is absolutely the wrong thing to do, because you don't own that memory!  The `vector` does, and as such will destroy each object for you when they are removed from the `vector`, including when the `vector` is cleared, or destroyed itself.

That being said, you are also modifying `player.projectiles` while iterating through it, so your loop WILL, at the very least, *skip elements* as elements are being erased, and *could* even go out of bounds.  You MUST NOT increment the `i` counter on iterations where `erase()` is called, eg:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < player.projectiles.size(); )
{
    if (player.projectiles[i].move(begin, WIDTH))
        player.projectiles.erase(player.projectiles.begin() + i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Alternatively, [`vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) returns an *iterator* to the next element following the one being erased, so have your loop use iterators instead of indexes, eg:

```cpp
for(auto iter = player.projectiles.begin(); iter != player.projectiles.end(); )
{
    if (iter->move(begin, WIDTH))
        iter = player.projectiles.erase(iter);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace the whole loop by using the [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom via [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

player.projectiles.erase(
    std::remove_if(player.projectiles.begin(), player.projectiles.end(),
        [=](auto &projectile) { return projectile.move(begin, WIDTH); }
    ),
    player.projectiles.end()
);
```

Or, [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) in C++20:

```cpp
std::erase_if(
    player.projectiles,
    [=](auto &projectile) { return projectile.move(begin, WIDTH); }
);
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `std::remove_if` here since the entire loop can be simplified to 2 lines (or 1 if you really don't mind smashing this together): `auto it = std::remove_if(player.projectiles.begin(), player.projectiles.end(), [](auto &projectile) { return projectile.move(begin, WIDTH); });` and subsequently `player.projectiles.erase(it, player.projectiles.end());`